# normalization in image processing

Tags: image-processing, normalization

What is the correct mean of normalization in image processing? I googled it but i had different definition. I'll try to explain in detail each definition.

**Normalization of a kernel matrix**

If normalization is referred to a matrix (such as a kernel matrix for convolution filter), usually each value of the matrix is divided by the sum of the values of the matrix in order to have the sum of the values of the matrix equal to one (if all values are greater than zero). This is useful because a convolution between an image matrix and our kernel matrix give an output image with values between 0 and the max value of the original image. But if we use a sobel matrix (that have some negative values) this is not true anymore and we have to stretch the output image in order to have all values between 0 and max value.

**Normalization of an image**

I basically find two definition of normalization. The first one is to "cut" values too high or too low. i.e. if the image matrix has negative values one set them to zero and if the image matrix has values higher than max value one set them to max values. The second one is to linear stretch all the values in order to fit them into the interval [0, max value].

Comment: This would be more appropriate in computer science.

Comment: How can I move the question in computer science?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I will extend a bit the answer from @metsburg. There are several ways of normalizing an image (in general, a data vector), which are used at convenience for different cases:

- [Data normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(image_processing)) or data (re-)scaling: the data is projected in to a predefined range (i.e. usually `[0, 1]` or `[-1, 1]`). This is useful when you have data from different formats (or datasets) and you want to normalize all of them so you can apply the same algorithms over them. Is usually performed as follows:

  ```
  Inew = (I - I.min) * (newmax - newmin)/(I.max - I.min)  + newmin
  ```
- [Data standarization](http://www.dataminingblog.com/standardization-vs-normalization/) is another way of normalizing the data (used a lot in machine learning), where the mean is substracted to the image and dividied by its standard deviation. It is specially useful if you are going to use the image as an input for some machine learning algorithm, as many of them perform better as they assume features to have a gaussian form with `mean=0,std=1`. It can be performed easyly as:

  ```
  Inew = (I - I.mean) / I.std
  ```
- [Data stretching](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dip/Histogram_Stretching.htm) or (histogram stretching when you work with images), is refereed as your option 2. Usually the image is clamped to a minimum and maximum values, setting:

  ```
  Inew = I
  Inew[I < a] = a
  Inew[I > b] = b
  ```

  Here, image values that are lower than `a` are set to `a`, and the same happens inversely with `b`. Usually, values of `a` and `b` are calculated as percentage thresholds. `a`= the threshold that separates bottom 1% of the data and `b`=the thredhold that separates top 1% of the data. By doing this, you are removing [outliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) (*noise*) from the image.
   This is similar (*simpler*) to [histogram equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization), which is another used preprocessing step.
- Data normalization, can also be refereed to a normalization of a vector respect to a norm ([l1 norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L1-Norm.html) or [l2/euclidean norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html)). This, in practice, is translated as to:

  ```
  Inew = I / ||I||
  ```

  where `||I||` refeers to a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) of `I`.

  If the norm is choosen to be the `l1` norm, the image will be divided by the sum of its absolute values, making the sum of the whole image be equal to `1`. If the norm is choosen to be `l2` (or euclidean), then image is divided by the sum of the square values of `I`, making the sum of square values of `I` be equal to `1`.

The first 3 are widely used with images (not the 3 of them, as *scaling* and *standarization* are incompatible, but 1 of them or *scaling + streching* or *standarization + stretching*), the last one is not that useful. It is usually applied as a preprocess for some statistical tools, but not if you plan to work with a single image.

Comment: I have a question, how did people come up with this linear function for data normalization? Are there other linear functions that will do the same? Thanks

Comment: @andres.santana Any linear function will map your image if you treat is as an array of grayscsle/colour values.

Comment: Is it correct ?

`Inew = (I - I.min) * (newmax - newmin) / (I.max - I.min)  + newmin`

Comment: @jakeoung yup you are right. I did put it the other way around (bad copying from wikipedia). Fixed in the post, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Answer by @Imanol is great, i just want to add some examples:

Normalize the input either **pixel** wise or **dataset** wise. Three normalization schemes are often seen:

1. Normalizing the pixel values between 0 and 1:

```
img /= 255.0
```

2. Normalizing the pixel values between -1 and 1 (as [Tensorflow](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py#L47-L50) does):

```
img /= 127.5
img -= 1.0
```

3. Normalizing according to the dataset mean & standard deviation (as [Torch](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py#L52-L55) does):

```
img /= 255.0
mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406] # Here it's ImageNet statistics
std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

for i in range(3): # Considering an ordering NCHW (batch, channel, height, width)
    img[i, :, :] -= mean[i]
    img[i, :, :] /= std[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

In data science, there are two broadly used normalization types:

1) Where we try to shift the data so that there sum is a particular value, usually 1 (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62353/what-does-it-mean-to-use-a-normalizing-factor-to-sum-to-unity)

2) Normalize data to fit it within a certain range (usually, 0 to 1): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range

Comment: So there are all three of them true and actually used?

Comment: Yes, all of them are used, but each have their own properties. Check @imaluengo's answer for details.